# best cross platform environment between ESP32 Local LCD and Android/IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am likely asking for the impossible here but I am building an ESP32 based LCD UX display.  The ESP32 is also going to be my Bluetooth and Webserver.

Right now my plans are:

- -use platformio with c++ and LVGL for the ESP32 and local LCD
- -Flutter via Bluetooth for my connected Android/IOS connected devices
- -c++/HTML/BS5/ReAct for the webserver

I basically want to create the same UX experience on the LCD, mobile app and browser, without having to replicate it 3 times.

Can anyone suggest a way to reduce my UX coding redundancy from LVGL, HTML and Flutter to a single cross platform environment?
Even if I could get from 3 down to just 2, that would be great.

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you see [Flutter on the web](https://flutter.dev/multi-platform/web)?

Comment: Actually I remembered it today and it looks like there are some good esp32 Flutter libraries I can explore.  Thanks Morrison, that brings it down to 2